# Python doesn't know about russian letters

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm writing my code in Python.

```
import requests
import time

connection = False

while True:
        while connection == False:
            try:
                response = requests.get('http://localhost:3000/command/connect')
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    connection = True
                    print('Successfully connected')
            except:
                print('Error')

        while True:
            try:
                response = requests.get('http://localhost:3000/command/check')
                print(response.content)
                time.sleep(60)
            except:
                connection = False
                break
```

And when I print the response.content on russian letters, I had this bug:

```
b'{"id":0,"msg":"\xd0\xb0"}'
```

But in msg must be russian letters. Can you help to solve this problem?

Comment: is this what you expect `'{"id":0,"msg":"а"}'`?

Comment: Yes, quite right

Comment: Instead of using `response.content` you should be using `response.text`.  Then do as suggested in the answers and use a JSON library to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And when I print the response.content on russian letters, I had this bug:

There is no bug. You're printing the "raw" binary response content, which is UTF8-encoded JSON:

```py
>>> b'{"id":0,"msg":"\xd0\xb0"}'.decode()
'{"id":0,"msg":"а"}'
```

JSON-decoding will take care of decoding and parsing the structure:

```py
>>> json.loads(b'{"id":0,"msg":"\xd0\xb0"}')
{'id': 0, 'msg': 'а'}
```

and `requests` has first-class support for JSON: just call `response.json()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug, you are receiving a binary response, so you nee do use use `json.loads` in order to parse it:

```py
import json


r = json.loads(b'{"id":0,"msg":"\xd0\xb0"}'.decode())
print(r, type(r))
```

**Output:**

```py
{'id': 0, 'msg': 'а'} <class 'dict'>
```